# How does OpenGL know how to use the normal data with glDrawElements()?

Tags: opengl, graphics

I spent days to construct a working example of rendering a cube in OpenGL with simple lighting

I have:

```
vertices = {...};
normals = {...};
vertex_indices = {...};
normal_indices = {...};
```

(1) I setup my VBOs

```
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertSize, &vertices[0]); // vertices
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertSize, normSize, &normals[0]); // normals
```

(2) I enable my vertex pointers

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,..)

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1,..)
```

(3) I also setup my index buffer

```
 glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indcSize, & vertex_indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

and then call `glDrawElements` in my render method

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (int)vertex_indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

I don't pass the normal indices anywhere but everything seems to work fine.

I don't think I understand glDrawElements correctly. How did the lighting work without the normal indices? was glDrawElements suppose to only get the vertex indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't think I understand glDrawElements correctly. How did the lighting work without the normal indices? was glDrawElements suppose to only get the vertex indices?

In OpenGL, there are no separate indices per attribute. As far as OpenGL is concerned, a vertex is an n-tuple of *all* attributes, like position, color, normal vector, tex coords, whatever.

In the case of your cube, you will need at least 24 vertices. There are only 8 corner positions, but each corner is connected to 3 different faces, each with a different normal. This means, that you need *3* separate vertices at each corner, all at the same position, but all differing by their normal direction.

Consequently, `glDrawElements` works with only one index array, and this is the index into *all enabled vertex attribute arrays* at the same time. Your `normal_indices` array is not used at all. If it still works as intended, your normal data happens to be organized in the correct way.

Comment: Thanks makes total sense to me now and yes the normal indices were ordered and that's why it worked I guess. What if they weren't ordered? How do I pass them to glDrawElements?

Comment: @nevermind: you never pass them. You'll have to reorder your normal data if it's not ordered the same as the position data, so that it becomes ordered the same as position. As derhass mentions that might mean duplicating position data, if the same position was used by multiple normals